# Deeplinking to Spotify Playlist without Starting the Music on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, spotify, deep-linking

When a user presses a button in my Android app, I'd like to deeplink them to a specified playlist on Spotify and NOT start the playlist. Or, if necessary, have the playlist start music and then immediately Pause/Stop the music.

I have most of it figured out below:

```
String spotifyPackageName = "com.spotify.music";
String viewAction = Intent.ACTION_VIEW;
String spotifyUriString = "spotify:user:" + userId + ":playlist:" + playlistId + ":play";
Uri spotifyUri = Uri.parse(spotifyUriString);

Intent spotifyIntent = new Intent(viewAction, spotifyUri);
spotifyIntent.setPackage(spotifyPackageName);

startActivity(spotifyIntent);
```

I am unsure about the correct Intent action to use to open up the playlist without automatically starting the music. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The music starts playing automatically since there is a ":play" at the end of the Spotify Uri you are providing.

If you would like to open the playlist but not have it start playing automatically you should change the Uri to following.

```
String spotifyUriString = "spotify:user:" + userId + ":playlist:" + playlistId;
```